# Long condition C++

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, increment

```
y=20;
x=32640;
b=1920;
if (
    n > (x*1) && n < ((x*1)+(b))||
    n > (x*2) && n < ((x*2)+(b))||
    n > (x*3) && n < ((x*3)+(b))||
    n > (x*4) && n < ((x*4)+(b))||
    n > (x*5) && n < ((x*5)+(b))||
    n > (x*6) && n < ((x*6)+(b))||
    n > (x*7) && n < ((x*7)+(b))||
    n > (x*8) && n < ((x*8)+(b))||
    n > (x*9) && n < ((x*9)+(b))||
    n > (x*10) && n < ((x*10)+(b))
    ){y = 40;}
```

In C++ is there a quicker way to do this as I only increment the number after 32640 for each condition?

(quicker in performance)

Comment: every condition is trying to find if n is between 2 numbers... the numbers are only incremental multiples of 32640. I thought that was quite clear.. and don't understand down-votes without explanation

Comment: Sounds like the remainder operator (`%`) will come to the rescue here.

Comment: ok i will look that up thanks Oli

Comment: @BENZ.404 I didn't downvote your question but your code should use constants for more readability.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic and better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) because it is about finding a better way to perform a specific task.

Comment: there are too many stackoverflow sites, you can't have one for code and one for reviewing code your idea is not good

Comment: @BENZ.404 No. `32640` seems to have special significance in your code. `x` is no different from `32640` - reading that won't tell anyone anything more than just reading the number. You should use constant names that are descriptive of the value they represent.

Comment: they are just numbers dude! 55555 (im only multiplying it)

Comment: What if the number changes from `32640` to another value and replacing every occurrence, you forget one?

Comment: Magic numbers in code lead to difficult code to decipher and maintain. As for the optimization question, you would have to first knowe what your compiler's own optimization turns this into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether this solution is more efficient, but maybe it is more readable and easier to code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    const int magicNumber = 32640;
    const int maxOffset = 1920;

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    int y = 20;

    const std::div_t divresult = std::div(n, magicNumber);

    if (divresult.rem > 0 && divresult.rem < maxOffset &&       // (#1)
            divresult.quot >= 1 && divresult.quot <= 10)    {   // (#2)
        y = 40;
    }

    std::cout << "y: " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Here, I make use of the fact that for your condition to be true, your variable to test (`n`) has to be between multiples of `32640` or `magicNumber` and multiples of that number plus some offset (`maxOffset`). This is the remainder of dividing your variable by the `magicNumber`, cf. (`#1`).

But this is not valid for every integer, but only for certain multiples, as expressed by the `||` in your original solution. In my solution, this is expressed by the quotient, cf. (`#2`).

While programming this answer, I learned that there is a function `std::div` that computes these two in one step and returns them in a structure of type `std::div_t`, so you can use the two members in the condition. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/div/) you can find more information on this function.

Comment: i can't read that dude, but thanks all the same

Comment: Sorry about that, but why can't you read that?

Comment: You really should include a description of what the code does and how it accomplishes it.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious included an explanation, thanks for the hint.

Comment: black bird you are too smart, my brain hurts, i need to some how make my iq higher so I can imagine what you said...